# Why time to execute multiple ajax calls increases for each call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page with a Google map. On page load, there is only one marker and the user can dynamically add  markers with a form.

I retrieve coordinates in database by using AJAX call. Each call return 150 markers. So, if I have to retrieve more markers, I do an other call until all markers are displayed on my map.

I have noticed (with load 2500 markers and firebug) time to execute server side action increases for each call.

Anyone can explain me why and if there is a way to fix it (because, at the end, calls take about 30s) ?

**EDIT :**

Execution time for each call (try to retrieve about 2500 markers) :

```
request 1  : 2.54s
request 2  : 1.83s
request 3  : 1.25s
request 4  : 1.31s
request 5  : 1.4s
request 6  : 1.81s
request 7  : 2.86s
request 8  : 8.25s
request 9  : 20.06s
request 10 : 19.25s
request 11 : 23.33s
request 12 : 25.86s
request 13 : 26.62s
request 14 : 27.85s
request 15 : 32.37s
request 16 : 34.91s
request 17 : 35.82s
request 18 : 36.7s
```

The function is exactly the same for each call and return value has same type and same length.

I do many calls in order to user can continue to work on map when markers are loading.

Comment: Could you post the code you have running in your AJAX call.

Comment: Looks to me that it has something to do with server-side stuff rather than AJAX.

Comment: Can you call single request without calling previous requests? I.e., try calling only request 14 and see if it alone takes 28 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a session_start in the called script, then only a single call can execute concurrently because the session file is locked until the first call script terminates and releases that lock, or it's manually released with a call to session_write_close(), wherupon the next queued call can run and lock the file in turn.

It might be easier to use a single call to retrieve all the marker data in one go, rather than a lot of single calls for each group of 150 marker entries... this will bypass any session locking issues, because only a single script is being executed; and is also more efficient for the network overheads

Comment: I have try to retrieve all markers in one request, but it's too long, and the request is stopped before finish. Thanks for explanation but, it don't explain why time increase (I edit my post to show you responses).

Comment: In that case, try using session_write_close() in your script to manually release the lock as early as you possibly can.